# Using App Access Token for Facebook Timeline Feeds

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I have started on developing a server side application that requires integration with facebook. My needs is an access token that will not expire, but unfortunately facebook has removed the offline_access feature and replaced with a long-live user access token that will last only 60 days.

I realise that there is an Application Access Token that will not expire. When I use it instead of the User Access Token to fetch the feed, I get must less information.

I have read from other sources that as long as relevant permissions are delegated, such as read_stream is given, using the application access token should allow the server-side application to access the users information that accepted the facebook application.

Am I mistaken ? Can anyone help to clarify ? Thanks

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Excerpt from: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-app-tokens/

While an App Access Token is largely for the purposes of publishing information back to Facebook on behalf of the user, there is a limited set of information that can be retrieved from Facebook using an App Access Token.

- Basic Profile Info of a User (ID, Name, Username, Gender)
- A User’s Friends and their IDs
- Permissions granted by the User to your App

So there is a limited set of info you can get using an app access token. So you probably don't want to use it to get the user's feed.